# How do I copy and transpose paste each row in range onto a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which has different data on it. I want to copy, transpose paste each row in a specified range onto a separate worksheet for each row. I'm pretty much stuck as I'm fairly new to this.

I don't quite understand where to proceed from this.

```
Sub LoopRow()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A6:AI57")

For Each row In rng.Rows


End Sub
```

Comment: Should each row have its own separate worksheet?

Comment: If yes, then how would you name all of them ? and you are talking about 151 sheets.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

All you need to do is change the Sheet Name. We are looping through the specified range and copy pasting each row on another sheets column with Transpose.

```
Sub LoopRow()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = Worksheets("Name of sheet where data is").Range("A6:AI57")

i = 1
For Each row In rng.Rows

    row.Copy
    Worksheets("Name where you want your data to go").Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```

It will paste the data from 1st cell. You can change that by changing `cells(2,i)` for second and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this macro

```
   Option Explicit
Sub TranPose_Range()
Dim rng As Range

'Source_sheet====>> name of sheet where the data is
'Target_sheet====>> name of sheet where you want your data to go
   Set rng = Sheets("Source_sheet").Range("A6").CurrentRegion
   rng.Copy
   Sheets("Target_sheet").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True

End Sub
```